# Can't figure out what is happening with this HTML/CSS.

Tags: html, css

I am developing a personal website and I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure out the resulting display of the following HTML and CSS code.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul class="navlist">
        <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Whatever</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  border: 1px dotted lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.navlist li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.navlist li a {
  padding: 25px;
}
```

In particular:

- Why is the top padding of the `<a>` elements not recognized/displayed right?
- Why is the height of the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements the same as the height of the `<a>` elements, with the padding of the latter "overflowing"  bottom?
- I'd like the height of the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements to be the same as that of the `<a>` elements including its padding, so the list items stay vertically centered, with same amount of padding at top and bottom. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting them to behave as a block level element but `<a>` is an *inline element* and things like `width`, `height`, `padding` and `margin` do not behave like they would if they were a *block level* element.

Set your anchor elements to `display: inline-block;` if you want the to accept things like `width`, `height`, `padding` and `margin`.

Unless you're going to add additional elements to your `.navlist` `<ul>` you can simplify your CSS selector for the anchor elements in that `<ul>` to the following, which effectively removes the additional specificity that wasn't needed in the original selector.

```
.navlist a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kcofsrxh/1

Answer (score 1):

`A` is an inline element. To make it behave as block-level element, add `display: block;` declaration:

```css
.navlist A {display: block; }
```

By the way, if the menu is intended to occupy exactly one line without wrapping over multiple lines, it may make sense to use `display: table` for `UL` element and `display: table-cell` for `LI` elements. This would automatically remove (typically undesired) whitespace between items.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried what you suggested but I need the list items to stay in the same line horizontally.

Comment: @Rafuka `inline-block` for parent element (`LI` in your case; you already have it) should be enough at least for modern browsers. Alternatively, make `LI` inline with `display: inline`, and apply `display: inline-block` to links themselves. Or use `display: table` (see the updated answer).